# Modular arithmetic calculation

Tags: math, modular

Is there any way to calculate `(a mod c)*(b mod c)`?

Knowing only:

- `a*b`
- `c`
- `d`
- `((a mod c)*(b mod c)) mod c`
- `(a mod d)*(b mod d)`

Comment: I think this is a question more relevant to ask in the Math Exchange community.

Comment: Then I'll try there too.

Comment: Are you asking for the algorithm or what?

Comment: I'm just curious is this possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: The last three "knowns" seem to be redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

Here's a counterexample:

```
ab = 1225 = (5)(5)(7)(7)
c = 3
d = 5000
((a mod c)(b mod c)) mod c = 1
(a mod d)(b mod d) = 1225
```

If a=25 and b=49, then (a mod c)(b mod c)=(1)(1)=1

If a=35 and b=35, then (a mod c)(b mod c)=(2)(2)=4